# Move Add To Cart button to right sidebar

Tags: cart

We are just implementing a Magento store (migrating form OSCommerce) and are trying to move the Add To Cart button (for Simple, Grouped and Configurable products) to the right column sidebar - we have a three column layout.

We have been having very unpredictable results with moving the cart and/or options to the right column - total items wrong on add to basket, alerts to 'to add to basket' even though products have been added etc.

All attempts so far have resulted in broken add to cart functionality.  Has anyone else succeeded with this?

Thanks

Shaun

Answer (score 1):

The Add to cart button is a submit button inside a form. Moving it out of the form into the right column will break it. You have two options:

1. Modify the template files so that the form encompasses the middle and right columns.
2. Have the button submit the main form via javascript.